# Is there a term for a period of one hundred and forty-four years?

Tags: single-word-requests

This question has been nagging at my mind. I want to write a story in an alternative world, and the primary culture will place importance on sets of 144 years, rather than centuries. I do not want to call them centuries for reader convenience; the sense of 'one hundred' is too embedded in the word.

If there is no existing word, is there a coinage that would be easily and readily understandable by native speakers?

Comment: I edited your question to include a rough guideline for your desire to invent a word, in an attempt to help keep the focus narrow and topical. You should feel free to rollback my edits or make more improvements of your own.

Comment: Bilbo's 144th birthday was the day he left the Shire in *Fellowship of the Rings,* right?  I don't remember him having a special word there, though maybe there was and maybe someone will remember it.

Comment: @jejorda One hundred and eleventy, not 144th.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Oh right, and the 144 was the number of guests because it was Frodo's age added to Bilbo's.  So that's a dead end.

Comment: If they count in base 12 you could still call them centuries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, the first minute division of an hour into 60 parts is called a minute, and the second division of those into 60 parts is called the second.

Perhaps you could use a system where the first grouping of months into 12 is the year, the second grouping (144 months or 12 years) is the second-month, and the third grouping (1728 months or 144 years) is the third-month.  Or just the *third.*

After explaining it once, it will be pretty easy to understand.

Comment: This is about as good as I will get, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used "a [gross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_(unit)) of years", and I'm not sure many people would understand, but I don't see a particular need for a more specific word.

Comment: The edit to the original question makes it quite different. In an alternative world, feel free to invent . . . Why the importance of 144 years? One could call it a Gross Year, a Great Year, a Long Year (Asaro used that for a period of 20 short-years), or more simply a Cycle or a Circuit.

Answer (score 3):

144 is a [dozen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dozen) dozens, or one [gross](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gross)

That's all I could find. New words are made every day. But only if there is some use for those words, they will stand the test of time. So you may create a word for it, but nobody would understand it.

But of course, if you're famous, anything you make up may become a meme and survive for a while, at least.

Comment: If it is an alternative world, you can make up a name.  Perhaps *grossyear*.

Answer (score 2):

Roman numerals for 144 is CXLIV, perhaps you can use that as a basis for invention/pronunciation of a word. I can imagine it morphing to something like 'Zellif' for example.